# How to detect swipe in Libgdx without triggering justTouched()?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm making a game where swiping and justTouched do different things. My problem is that when I swipe on the screen obviously the touchDown() method is also being triggered.

Im extending GestureAdapter:

```
@Override
    public boolean touchDown(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        //move when screen is touched
        if(life == 1 && overlaps == false) {
            timeState = 0;
            velocity.y = -120;
            velocity.x = 100;
        }
        return super.touchDown(x, y, pointer, button);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean fling(float velocityX, float velocityY, int button) {
        if(velocityX > 10)
            //do something
        return super.fling(velocityX, velocityY, button);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not use just touched in this case because when player touched first time you cant know  will it be just touch or swipe.

You must use justtouched with touch up method like this

1. when player justtouched save touched coordinates.
2. Check coordinates when player touched up.
3. If distance between this 2 points less than 50 pixels (or what limit you want to set) then you can assume its justtouched otherwise its swipe and you can do calculations about swiping.

Comment: thanks but I just implemented JestureListener which has a tap() method which resolve the problem between the fling method.